# DynamoDB returning Numbers as decimals not integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-ruby

I’m storing a few numbers in a Map. They’re being set correctly, and appear in DynamoDB interface correctly:

```
results List [1]
    0 Map
        dateTimeCompleted Number : 1554138543
        questionsAnswered Number : 10
        questionsCorrect Number : 5
```

However, when I get the response, using the AWS Ruby SDK, they’ve turned into decmimals.

```
"dateTimeCompleted"=>0.1554376141e10,
"questionsAnswered"=>0.2e2,
"questionsCorrect"=>0.5e1
```

*Note this aren’t from the same item, so I’m aware the numbers don’t match,  the format is the concern.*

How do I tell the SDK that I’d like them as integers?

*or*

Do I need to map them in Ruby to integers myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_i`:

```
0.1554376141e10.to_i # => 1554376141
```

To convert all the values in a Hash:

```
my_hash.reduce({}) { |memo, (k,v)| memo[k] = v.to_i; memo }
```

or:

```
my_hash.transform_values(&:to_i)
```

Comment: `transform_values` is a great shout, I was hoping for something that could be done at a DynamoDB level, but I think you might be the closest I can get to for now!

Comment: Fortunately, floats can represent whole numbers exactly.